Is there a way to create a policy (SCP) in AWS IAM that prevents tag creation with whitespace as a value?
I am trying to prevent tag creation with white space as a value on the following Tag "owner"
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "cloudformation:CreateStack"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals": {
          "aws:TagKeys": [
            "owner",
            "Owner"
          ]
        },
        "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Owner": "* *"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

This still lets me create the tag with white space as a value.
Am I using the correct condition for this case? Thanks for any suggestions!

If your need is to deny one action "cloudformation:CreateStack" you can do somthing like this :
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyTagOwnerWithWhitespace",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "cloudformation:CreateStack"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:RequestTag/owner": [
            " *",  // Leading whitespace
            "* ",  // Trailing whitespace
            "*\t*", // Tab
            "*\n*", // Newline
            "*\r*", // Carriage return
            "*\f*"  // Form feed
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

but I belive your use case is more suitable with tagging policy, somthing like this from here :
{
    "tags": {
        "costcenter": {
            "tag_key": {
                "@@assign": "CostCenter"
            },
            "tag_value": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "100",
                    "200"
                ]
            },
            "enforced_for": {
                "@@assign": [
                    "secretsmanager:*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

bear in mind that you you can enforce Tag key capitalization compliance, Tag value compliance and Prevent noncompliant operations for this tag, for more explanation for each one of them check this
